# Transform scale transition not working in Safari only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

Ok, Ive looked at similar questions but nothing is working in my case - I have a transform scale/transition that is not working in Safari only. The scale happens but it snaps - no transition. Code:

```
.site-title a {
  img {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1.4, 1, 1) 0s;
    -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1.4, 1, 1) 0s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1.4, 1, 1) 0s;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 1.4, 1, 1) 0s;
  transition-duration: 300ms;
  }
}
 .site-title a:hover {
 img {
   transform: scale(1.03);
   content: url("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/file-hosting-723cd.appspot.com/o/Asset%201.png?alt=media&token=07551984-08b6-4c8e-99b4-69280e148aa2")
}
 }
 .site-title a:selected {

 img {
   transform: scale(1.03);
   content: url("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/file-hosting-723cd.appspot.com/o/Asset%201.png?alt=media&token=07551984-08b6-4c8e-99b4-69280e148aa2")
}
 }
```

Ive added every kind of transition but Safari crosses some out. Whats wrong here?

Comment: It appears you never specify the transition property, only the duration and timing function, so I'm not sure how it would be working in any browser. If you add that and it's still not working, a stack snippet so people can actually test in Safari would be great.

Comment: share a working example...it will be easy for us to resolve the issue....

Comment: The content CSS property is used with the ::before and ::after pseudo-elements to generate content in an element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code.

```
img {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```